# addOnScreenMenu - Change properties of the main button

Tags: lightningchart

I'm working with the .addOnScreenmenu method on a ChartXY.

Demo: https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0706-onScreenMenu.html?theme=lightNew&page-theme=light&isList=false

Documentation: https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.4.0/classes/chartxy.html#addonscreenmenu

I found that you can change the size of the fly out menu icons by changing the dimension, but I can't seem to find a way to change the size of the main button that triggers the fly out. Thoughts?